# Can someone please help me find the Keyboard Layout Preview for Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout

I can't seem to find this since the last update.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Ramhound: That sounds like an answer. Since your comment is rather old I’ll write a wiki answer citing your comment. You can notify me of your own answer and I’ll remove mine.

Comment: I have unsuccessfully tried to apply steps to display the "Keyboard layout preview" either. The choices found in some guidance like here [isunshare.com preview-keyboard-layout-in-windows-10](https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/preview-keyboard-layout-in-windows-10.html) simply are not there. The issue is not to add/remove KBD layout, but to preview layouts. That is quite essential feature, present in earlier windows and any Linux distro, if one uses layouts different to HW keyboard layout.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Ramhound](/questions/1328954/can-someone-please-help-me-find-the-keyboard-layout-preview-for-windows-10#comment1983877_1328954):

> It no longer exists. How you add and remove languages is entirely performed in Settings the legacy UI you provided no longer exists in 1803.